# My Visual Studio Code cannot recognize the "async" keyword

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am following the tutorial on udemy.com and soon I realize "async" keyword doesnt "highlighted" as the "await" keyword[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code and an image of what you see?

Comment: you may need to turn on es6 feature

Comment: @brk `async`/`await` is ES2017 IIRC - so ES8.

Comment: @JackBashford I added my package.json code,I hope that will provide some helpful information

Comment: What color theme are you using? It probably doesn't have highlighting for that.

Comment: @Herohtar Hmmm I think it is color theme issue